# Disable chat-heads (for WhatsApp, etc.) on Samsung devices

Tags: samsung, notifications, whatsapp-messenger, 9.0-pie

After an Android 9.0 Pie update on my Samsung Galaxy Note 8, I have noticed that Whatsapp Messenger notifications come up similar to how Facebook Messenger notifications are delivered - with a chat head. This is a circle with the messenger's profile picture showing, and clicking on it opens a small window with the message shown.

I preferred when this chat head was never there, and I got to see a preview of the message for a few seconds just below the top of the screen when a message arrives.

I have tried turning off pop-up notifications on WhatsApp, but this seems to be something different entirely, as the chat heads continue to come up.

Is it possible to turn this feature off?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Follow this path to enable or disable the mentioned "chat heads":

Settings > Advanced features > Smart pop-up view

Then, toggle whatever applications you'd like to show "chat heads".

Answer (score 2):

WhatsApp does not naively support chat heads. So, this is being done by using a third party app. Probably you installed one, or in a rare case your phone manufacturer baked such a thing into the phone UI.
Please look into your device settings and also go through your installed apps if you notice something.

Comment: Actually, it does. I found [this post](https://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s9-s9-plus/932806-anyone-else-having-whatsapp-chat-heads-after-s9-pie-update.html) on another forum where people have the same problem. I haven't installed any such third party app.

Comment: @JohnDoe interesting. Then this is something being done by the OEM. As I said, WhatsApp doesn't support such a thing natively. And as Firelord said and per your comment, it must be the Pop-up windows.